# Zend Framework Form not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

In my `public/index.php` I define the include path:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/var/www/php_include/zend/1.11.7/library',
    '/var/www/php_include/application',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

In my IndexController I want to reference to my Form with

```
new Form_Login();
```

But there I receive the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'LoginForm' not found in /var/www/php_include/application/controllers/LoginController.php on line 31

Form is under `application/forms/Login.php`:

```
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
```

`get_include_path()` before using `new LoginForm()` throws:

> /var/www/php_include/application/../library:/var/www/php_include/zend/1.11.7/lib‌​rary:/var/www/php_include/application:/var/www/php_include/application/forms:.:/v‌​ar/www/php_include:/usr/share/pear/PEAR

Anyone knows how to get this working?

Comment: Could you add the definition of your LoginForm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoloader won't find it me sphinx. Just add your `forms/` path to your include path.

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/var/www/php_include/zend/1.11.7/library',
    '/var/www/php_include/application',
    '/var/www/php_include/application/forms',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Now rename your file to `LoginForm.php` and your class-name to `LoginForm`

Then use

```
new LoginForm();
```

This is the exact same way I have done it with my projects, except my forms-dir is placed in views and the includepath is set with application.ini

**Update**

This is part of my Bootstrap class:

```
function _initAutoloader() {
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Comment: form is under "forms/LoginForm.php" and starting with "class LoginForm extends Zend_Form". Added "/var/www/php_include/application/forms" to public/index.php. Using "new LoginForm();" to get it... still -> Fatal error: Class 'LoginForm' not found in /var/www/php_include/application/controllers/LoginController.php on line 31

Comment: I receive no error from the message stack, only from php. And get_include_path() before using new LoginForm() throws: /var/www/php_include/application/../library:/var/www/php_include/zend/1.11.7/library:/var/www/php_include/application:/var/www/php_include/application/forms:.:/var/www/php_include:/usr/share/pear/PEAR

Comment: maybe the problem is in the application.ini?

Comment: Hmm.. maybe MY autoloader is actually in effect, thus it works for me. Så may YOUR autoloader is not working propperly. I have updated my answer with a part of my bootstrap class.

Comment: This was it :) THANKS SO MUCH! I am really needed to have a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Comment: see the resourcetype loader in special.

Answer (score 1):

your class should be called
`Form_LoginForm` to be found by the autoloader.

But you should change it to `Form_Login` and `forms/Login.php`

Comment: Changed to "class Form_Login" and renamed to /forms/Login.php does not work :/

Comment: Aren't the 's' in forms directory going to mess things up? what if you rename `forms/` to `form/` ?

Comment: doesn't matter. same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new Default_Form_LoginForm();
```